# Are Scala closures as flexible as C++ lambdas?

Tags: scala, c++11, lambda

I know the question seems a bit heretical. Indeed, having much appreciated lambdas in C++11, I was quite thrilled to learn a language which was built to support them from the beginning rather than as a contrived addition.

However, I cannot figure out how to do with Scala all I can do with C++11 lambdas.

Suppose I want to make a function which adds to a number passed as a parameter some value contained in a variable `a`. In C++, I can do both

```
int a = 5;
auto lambdaVal = [ a](int par) { return par + a; };
auto lambdaRef = [&a](int par) { return par + a; };
```

Now, if I change `a`, the second version will change its behavior; but the first will keep adding `5`.

In Scala, if I do this

```
var a = 5
val lambdaOnly = (par:Int) => par + a
```

I essentially get the `lambdaRef` model: changing `a` will immediately change what the function does. 
(which seems somewhat specious to me given that this time `a` isn't even mentioned in the declaration of the lambda, only in its code. But let it be)

Am I missing the way to obtain `lambdaVal`? Or do I have to first copy `a` to a `val` to be free to modify it afterwards without side effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` in the function definition refers the variable `a`. If you want to use the current value of `a` when the lambda has been created, you have to copy the value like this:

```
val lambdaConst = {
  val aNow = a
  (par:Int) => par + aNow
}
```

Comment: Well, if i can write in a single line `{val aNow = a; (par:Int) => par + aNow }`... it's not that longer than the c++ equivalent!

Comment: In general, it is preferable to avoid `var`s and to prefer `val`s anyway.

Comment: I guess that's what I was missing :) In my head at the moment most values are mutable, I'll have to change that!